# Javadoc cant see @params

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Anyone has an idea why my documentation doesn't recognize the parameters outside of the method? Usually I should be able to place the JavaDoc above a method but still reference the params, right?

[image]

Comment: Method signature doesn't have the specified parameters.

Comment: these methods dont take arguments. So how would i address it then in a javadoc

Comment: If the method doesn't take arguments, you don't document any arguments in JavaDoc.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to document variables created inside the method. Why not use ordinary comments just above such variables for this?